# Specify the Headers for Office 365 Push Notifications

Tags: aws-api-gateway, office365api, office365-restapi

I am creating Outlook subscriptions [as outlined here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/notify-rest-operations), and setting the NotificationURL to an endpoint on [AWS API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/). This works as expected.

However, the endpoint is now being locked down, and will require an authorization token and API key to access.

How can I set the headers on the push notifications being sent from Office 365?

Comment: did my answer help you?

Comment: Yes, thank you, and my apologies for taking so long to get back to you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think you can authenticate the request sent from Office 365 REST API services by setting a bearer or something like that.

The `NotificationURL` you give to Office 365 REST services must be accessible publicly. But the rest of your API can be accessible only through authentication. Of course you must implement/check the `ValidationToken` or `SubscriptionId` to avoid being hacked by malicious REST calls faking Outlook subscriptions.